# How can I use spark to writeStream data from a kafka topic into hdfs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs

I have been trying to get this code to work for hours:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder() 
.appName("Consumer") 
.getOrCreate() 

spark.readStream 
.format("kafka") 
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", url) 
.option("subscribe", topic) 
.load() 
.select("value") 
.writeStream 
.format(fileFormat) 
.option("path", filePath) 
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint") 
.start() 
.awaitTermination()
```

it gives this exception:

```
Logical Plan: 
Project [value#8] 
+- StreamingExecutionRelation KafkaV2[Subscribe[MyTopic]], [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13] 

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:295) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.SerializedOffset cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.reader.streaming.Offset 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:405) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:390) 
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241) 
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241) 
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893) 
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336) 
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.foreach(StreamProgress.scala:25) 
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.flatMap(StreamProgress.scala:25) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:390) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:390) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:389) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
```

I don't understand what's going on, I am simply trying to write data from a kafka topic into HDFS using spark streaming. Why is this so hard? And how can I do it?

I got the batching version to work just fine:

```
spark.read 
.format("kafka") 
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", url) 
.option("subscribe", topic) 
.load() 
.selectExpr("CAST(value AS String)") 
.write 
.format(fileFormat) 
.save(filePath)
```

Comment: Kafka Connect already does this, and is included in Kafka 0.10 and higher... Why write any code to do this?? https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-hdfs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@happy You are encountering a known bug in structured streaming https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25257

This is because the offset from disk is never deserialized and the fix will be merged in coming release

Comment: But it's fixed in Spark 2.4?

Comment: What fileFormat are you using ?

Comment: @cricket_007 I changed my spark version to 2.3.2 and everything started working!

Answer (score 0):

Everything started working after I changed my version of spark to `2.3.2`.